# WPF Textbox selection foreground color change

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the foreground color of a TextBox in WPF. Here is the code:

```
foreach (Match m in RedWord)
{
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = m.Index;
    TextBox1.SelectionLength = m.Length;
    TextBox1.Select(m.Index, m.Length);
    TextBox1.SelectionBrush = Brushes.Red;
    //EditorTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
}
```

The `.SelectionBrush` does not appear to apply the foreground text color as I need it. How can I change my text foreground color on selection?

Comment: Do you mean you want the **text** to be set to red, and the selection box thing to remain the same colour? Or, transparent? What I mean is that you want to apply the foreground only to text that has been selected?

Comment: Unfortunately, [you can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850629/how-to-change-the-highlighted-texts-foreground-color-for-a-wpf-textbox/10850718#10850718).

Answer (score 0):

For the highlight colour - you should do this in XAML.

```
<TextBox Text="hehehehehehehe adfasdfasdfds" SelectionBrush="Aquamarine" />
```

It works fine:

[image]

You cannot set the text colour (foreground) of selected text independently of unselected text.  The text colour is effectively coming from the system brush key (ControlTextBrushKey, I  think) - and it cannot be set separately.